# Computed property that tracks external variable in vue.js not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a computed property - playerId that is referencing an external object that is not updating.

For example:

```
var player = require('players');
computed: {
    playerId: function() {
         return player.id
    }
}
```

If I run this call in a click event it outputs the correct ID.  However when this gets updated  - computed on its own doesn't update. How do I get this to work?  Or am I going about this incorrectly?

Comment: Create an object in data property and return the object from computed property

Comment: @divine If I do this - how do I get the view to update?  Do I need to call something manually to render with the new value or should it update the view automatically?

Comment: you have to call the computed property on click

Answer (score 4):

Computed Property in Vue.js does not get reactive with the data which doesn't have any reactive dependecy. For example, the code below would **not** be updated in each time, because `Date.now()` has no reactive dependency. The result of this computed value gets cached and it always returns the same value as the one returned at the first time.

```
computed: {
  now: function () {
    return Date.now()
  }
}
```

Then, you probably would like to know how to make your external object reactive. The point is, you better put your object into `data` section in order to track the change of it with Vue's internal watcher. If your computed property has even one a reactive dependency such referencing `data` or calling `method`, it is notified every time the dependency get updated and the content returned from the computed property is going to be updated as well.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html